# PHP global variable error during function's calling

Tags: php, variables, global

I have the following function:

```
<?php

function deffunc($param1, $param2)
{
    global $var1;
    $var1 = "firstvar";
    echo $param1;
    echo "\n";
    echo $param2;
}

$var2 = "secondvar";

deffunc($var1, $var2);

?>
```

Calling the function will return a "Undefined variable" for $var1 but I don't understand why since it is global and defined inside the function's curly brackets.
However, if I use echo after the function's calling like this:

```
deffunc($var1, $var2);
echo $var1;
```

it will return the result "firstvar".
I do not understand why echo can read that global variable set inside the function, but if I call the function I get an "undefined variable" error.

Comment: You have to declare the global variable before you call the function.

Comment: The error stems from that there is no `$var1` in the scope of the function _call_ `deffunc($var1, $var2);` You are trying to open the front door from the outside here with the key that is inside the house …

Comment: hey, just following up to see if my answer helped? :)

Answer (score 0):

You have scope problem. `$var1` is only available inside the function. Declare `$var2` outside the function and then you can use it as a parameter to send to the function.

Comment: You could have written this in comment, aye?

Comment: @RahulMeshram - The OP was looking for an answer. The answer is, he's got a scope problem.

Comment: I thought "inside" the function means inside its curly brackets and "outside" the function means everywhere that is not inside the curly brackets. If this is true I don't see what do you mean by "declare $var2 outside the function" since it is declared outside of the brackets. And if  $var1 is indeed available only inside the function, then why the last echo $var1 which is placed outside the function can still print its value instead of a "Undefined variable" error.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `$var1` isn't declared prior to the function.

If we take a look at this PHP page: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php we can see that their example function has `$a` and `$b` declared beforehand. Your code should be written like this:

```
$var1 = 'some string';

function foo()
{
    global $var1;
    return $var1;
}

# this will output some string
echo '<pre>. print_r(foo()) .'</pre>'. "\n";
```

The reason this works is because a function has scope local to itself. If we declare a var beforehand then it's still not in the function without the use of the keyword `global`. Using this gets the variables from the `$_GLOBALS` array where the varname (`$var1`) matches the $_GLOBALS keyname (`var1`)